# Can't upload theme to wordpress - AWS Linux

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I've got wordpress running on a AWS Linux instance. 
I can create posts.
I can upload images.
But I can't upload themes.

Having messed about with the permissions this is where it currently stands:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 19935 Jan  2  2017 license.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  7413 Dec 12  2016 readme.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  5447 Sep 27  2016 wp-activate.php
drwxr-sr-x  9 apache apache  4096 Jun  8 14:29 wp-admin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache   364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  1627 Aug 29  2016 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  2825 Jul 27 21:21 wp-config.php
drwxr-sr-x  5 apache apache  4096 Jul 28 11:53 wp-content
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-sr-x 18 apache apache 12288 Jun  8 14:29 wp-includes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  2422 Nov 21  2016 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3301 Oct 25  2016 wp-load.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 34327 May 12 17:12 wp-login.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  8048 Jan 11  2017 wp-mail.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 16200 Apr  6 18:01 wp-settings.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache 29924 Jan 24  2017 wp-signup.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  4513 Oct 14  2016 wp-trackback.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  3065 Aug 31  2016 xmlrpc.php
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permissions for the **themes** folder inside wp-content folder.

Try running the following commands if it's CentOS:

**Changes ownership to Apache user and group**

```
chowm -R apache:apache /path-to-wp/wp-content/
```

**Change permissions and add setguid**

```
cd /path-to-wp/wp-content/
find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

This should hopefully resolve the file permissions and fix the uploads.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Still not doing it. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Niazipan Hello! Can you go inside wp-content and show me what the permissions are?

Comment: @Niazipan also could you check if it's not a max upload size issue?

Comment: permissions as follows:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jun  8 14:29 plugins
drwxrwsr-x 6 apache apache 4096 Jul 29 22:01 themes
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jul 29 22:02 uploads

Comment: where would I check max upload size?

Comment: what error does it give you when you try to upload the theme?

Comment: @Niazipan you can check the max upload size by navigating to Wp Dashboard > Media > Add New and at the bottom it should give you the max upload size.